# Spark Task not Serializable with simple accumulator?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, accumulator

I am running this simple code:

```
val accum = sc.accumulator(0, "Progress");
listFilesPar.foreach {
  filepath =>
    accum += 1
}
```

listFilesPar is an `RDD[String]`

which throws the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Right now I don't understand what's happening
and I don't put parenthesis but brackets because I need to write a lengthy function. I am just doing unit testing

Comment: What is the context in which this function is defined? In particular, what is the enclosing class?

Comment: I'm doing this on a spark shell that has its master pointed to a spark cluster

Comment: Can you post the whole code if it's not too long, please? I can try to reproduce it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical cause of this is that the closure unexpectedly captures something. Something that you did not include in your paste, because you would never expect it would be serialized.

You can try to reduce your code until you find it. Or just turn on serialization debug logging with `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true`. You will probably see in the output that Spark tries to serialize something silly.