# Spark Accumulator throws "Task not serializable" error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following is a simple 2-line code:

```
scala> val accum = sc.accumulator(0)

scala> sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).foreach(x => accum += x)
```

which gives the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1893)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:869)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:868)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:868)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
at <init>(<console>:65)
at .<init>(<console>:69)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf

Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkConf, value: org.apache.spark.SparkConf@77c34c76)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: conf, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkConf)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5a1a54a9)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@67df0f0c)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1d2cec35)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@28f41b13)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@23809ad0)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@511e5bf4)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@78cf5ef7)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@78823a7b)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1de73472)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@40fa4ed5)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@701b07c8)
- field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC, $iwC@644e6b9e)
- field (class: $line26.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
- object (class $line26.$read, $line26.$read@3cc485e8)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL42, type: class $line26.$read)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7a3a085c)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@9cc3ba0)
- field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
- object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:312)
... 59 more
```

I am using spark version 1.4.1 with scala 2.10.4.

**Edit:**
The above lines of code is taken from spark docs:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.Accumulator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Task not Serializable with simple accumulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980781/spark-task-not-serializable-with-simple-accumulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run this from spark shell directly, that will not work.

You have to make a function and call that from the shell like the following:

```
object Stack{
   def overFlow( ) : Unit = {
      val accum = sc.accumulator(0)
      sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).foreach(x => accum += x)
      println(accum.value)
   }
}
```

Now on calling the function, you should get your desired result:

```
scala> Stack.overFlow
10
```

Comment: It's due to the way scala creates vals. If the val is under a class or object, then the val is a field of the class or object. In that case, the closure (x=> accum += x) becomes (x => Stack.accum += x) which means Stack has to be serialized => no serialization exception